# pandas read_csv only works after opening csv and saving it again as csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I downloaded a csv from a website and have problems reading it using pandas.read_csv.
The structure of the CSV looks exemplary like this:

```
I              K     L
A  abcdefg. -,01  10,5
B    hijkl  -,01  12,3
C           mnop  14,0
D            NaN  -0,2
```

I only get the right output after I opened the csv manually and saved the file again as csv.

```
original = pd.read_csv('original.csv', sep=';', decimal=",")
saved_again = pd.read_csv('saved_again.csv', sep=';', decimal=",")

print(original)
    I  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2
0 NaN         NaN         NaN
1 NaN         NaN         NaN
2 NaN         NaN         NaN
3 NaN         NaN         NaN

print(saved_again)
   I              K     L
0  A  abcdefg. -,01  10.5
1  B    hijkl  -,01  12.3
2  C           mnop  14.0
3  D            NaN  -0.2
```

Does anyone have a clue on how I can fix this or how I can save the csv again as csv automatically?

Comment: Your original file is not a csv file: it certainly doesn't use `;` as a separator, so there's no point in reading it with `sep=';'`; you could try to read it as a csv with `delim_whitespace=True`, but formatting is inconsistent, rows have either 3 or 4 fields. I would suggest choosing a delimeter and then patching the file before reading into pandas.

Comment: As you expected delim_whitespace=True didn't work because of inconsistent number of fields in the lines. How can I patch the file before reading into pandas?

Comment: Have the "columns" in the original file fixed lengths (your sample looks like it)? If so, you could easily preprocess the file into a proper csv-file.

Comment: Yes, the length of the columns ist fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your original .csv file. Without it, however I suspect it has something to do with your encoding. What probably happens is when you manually open your file you "enforce" proper encoding that your python is "ready" to deal with. I would experiment with the "encoding" arg as follows:

```
pd.read_csv("original.csv", sep=';', decimal=",", encoding='UTF-16 LE')
```

Comment: Did not change the output. I also tried the encoding 'cp273' because I am from germany.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. requests.get().text returns a string with '\x00\x00\x00' in it:

```
text = requests.get('www.website.csv').text
print(text)
I\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00K\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00L\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00A\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00abcdefg. -,01\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x0010,5\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00B\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00hijkl  -,01\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x0012,3\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00mnop\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x0014,0\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00D\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00NaN\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00-0,2

print(text.replace('\x00',''))
I;K;L
A;abcdefg. -,01;10,5
B;hijkl  -,01;12,3
C;mnop;14,0
D;NaN;-0,2
```

And then i created a Dataframe and saved it as a csv:

```
lines = text.replace('\x00','').split('\n')
data = []

for count, line in enumerate(lines):
    if count == 0:     
        columns = line.split(';')
    else:
        data.append(line.split(';'))
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
df['L'] = df['L'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

This is probably not the smartest way, but it works.